# Excel formula's

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3 work sheets in a workbook each labelled as (HY 2015,HY 2016 & HY 2017) for the 3 years of data for all the different businesses in my dataset. In anyone sheet I may have multiple rows of data that relate to a single business ID which is unique to that business and held in column U on each sheet. It is also possible that I may have data only in a single or 2 years and not all 3 years.

I want to write a formula that looks at the business ID's in column U on sheet HY 2015 and then on column U on sheet HY 2016 and finally on column U on sheet HY 2017 and if it finds the same Business ID on all 3 sheets return on to each sheet in to column AD a number 1 for that corresponding row for that business ID.
Is this possible and if so how please?

Comment: `It is also possible that I may have data only in a single or 2 years and not all 3 years.` Yes, Data, Filter. For a better solution. You have to do much better in your question. Look at some questions to get an idea. You need to post your work, insert some images, do some work to show your dream sheet (how you wish it looks). It's not magic, it takes work and you have to do your best to show what you've done and how someone may assist you.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code that works for me in Cell AD2 of HY2017 sheet, based on what you describe. Since this an array formula, **remember to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>** instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then drag down your formula.

```
=IF(ISNA(INDEX(U:U,MATCH(U2&U2,'HY2016'!U:U&'HY2015'!U:U,0))),0,1)
```

This utilizes the INDEX-MATCH function with multiple criteria. Briefly, this match cell U2 twice in both the 2016 and 2015 sheets. The `IF(ISNA())` in the beginning is to set the output to 1 if all 3 business ID exist, 0 if they do not.

[image: Sample Excel screenshot]